# Total memory usage of a RTP application in Workbench/VxWorks

Tags: memory, rtp, workbench, vxworks

How can I determine the total memory usage of a RTP application in Workbench/VxWorks?

I know there is a Memory Analyzer tool but it does not seem to serve the purpose. When I use the Memory Analyzer, the total memory allocated to a process remains the same even after I increased the size of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not rely on exact numbers the [`memShow`](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/memShow.html#memShow) command of the VxWorks shell will do.

Start VxWorks without your application running and enter `memShow` this will give you the current memory usage of the system. Now start your application and do something you belive is the most memory intensive operation and enter `memShow` again. By subtracting the values of "current free bytes" you get a rough estimation of the memory usage of your application.